# How to migrate data from MySQL 5 to Sybase ASE 15.5?

Tags: mysql, database, sybase, sap-ase, powerdesigner

I've passed the database schema from MySQL to Sybase ASE using PowerDesigner.

---

Is there a tool to help migrating the data itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase has an old whitepaper in which they recommend using [EMS Data Export](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products) to extract the data from MySQL, and the Sybase **bcp** utility for imports.

Here are the other recommended tools

> The recommended tools for the migration are:
>
> • PowerTransfer Tool to stream the data from MySQL to ASE
>
> • InfoMaker™ with its Data Pipeline feature to move the data from MySQL directly into ASE
>
> • MS DTS to move the data from MySQL directly into ASE
>
> • BCP for moving the data.
>
> • CIS (Sybase Component Integration Services) and Enterprise Connect Data Access (ECDA) to extract data from MySQL and insert directly into ASE

AFAIK `PowerTransfer` was an old tool included with PowerDesigner, but is no longer available.

The whitepaper is a bit dated, [but it can be found here](http://www.sybase.com/files/White_Papers/MySQL-ASE-Guide-051507-wp.pdf).

A second option would be migrating the data to SQLAnywhere first, then using ASE Component Integration Services to move the data into your ASE instance.  The MySQL to SQLAnywhere instructions [can be found here](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1095051).